# Facebook Like Box Confirmation Page is not Working

Tags: facebook, http-status-code-404, facebook-likebox, confirmation

I'm currently working with Facebook Like Box.

I used the the official like box generator.
For the required input page, I use:
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Cinta-Buku/265954863527629

and the generator generates this code:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FCinta-Buku%2F265954863527629&amp;width=292&amp;height=590&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:590px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

*and it works.*

However, the problem is: every time I try to like the page using the box, I have to confirm it. After I clicked the link to the confirm page, it says "The page you requested was not found." But I am sure I inserted the right page to the generator.

Here is the screenshot for the confirmation page:

[image]

And here is the complete URL for the confirmation page:

```
https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like_confirm.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FCinta-Buku%2F265954863527629&node_type=page&edge_type=like&widget_id=connect_widget_50a60922e85357a20242337
```

I've tried using the debugger to check the facebook page. But the result is weird, I mean, how can a facebook-generated page does not pass the debugger? Maybe this debugger is not for Facebook page.

The closest question I found here in Stack Overflow is 'Facebook Like Button Confirmation Page Says “The Page You Requested Was Not Found”', but this one is for Like Widget, not Like Box, and the solution does not work for me.

You can try the problematic box here: http://www.cintabuku.co.id/
It's in the lower right sidebar.

So yeah, I'm kinda stumped here.
Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the problem as well. Let me guess... in the beginning the like box worked fine?

This happens because Facebook tries to scrape the url you want to like (in your case http://www.facebook.com/pages/Cinta-Buku/265954863527629), but if you put it into the debugger it gives an error that it can't be parsed. So after a while Facebook will mark the page as "spam" and then you have to confirm (what often doesn't work as well).

The reason why Facebook doesn't scrape the page correctly is because if the numbers in the url I think. Because if you try to scrape http://www.facebook.com/ with the debugger it works.

I don't really see a real solution for you here, we always have to like external pages and not a Facebook page itself, but still I hope you understand the problem a bit better now.

Comment: I see, thank you very much for your answer :D
I have to start looking for alternatives then...